# Does the definition of "mutually exclusive" include the case where neither A nor B happen?

Tags: logic

Does the definition of "mutually exclusive" include the case where neither A nor B happen?

I ask this because I remember in logic, "xor" has to be A or B and doesn't include the case where neither A nor B happen.

Here is an example that might help explain what I want to ask.

> A: seeing Superman

> B: seeing Clark Kent

We can only see either Superman or Clark Kent at a time, and never see them both, and **we see neither of them sometimes**.

In this case, can we say A and B are mutually exclusive?

Comment: "A and B are mutually exclusive" means **only** that A and B can't happen at the same time. (But I think this question would be more appropriate at e.g. https://english.stackexchange.com/, there isn't really a philosohpy aspect here.)

Comment: Yes, it includes it. To exclude neither happening the term is "collectively exhaustive". See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusivity) or dictionaries for these types of questions

Answer (score 1):

"Mutually exclusive" means [either one excludes the other](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mutually%20exclusive) and is synonymous with the concept of [disjointness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_sets).
In logic terms, "A and B are mutually exclusive" should be written as (A IMPLIES (NOT B)) AND (B IMPLIES (NOT A)).
If we make a truth table for this, we see its truth value is TRUE when A = B = FALSE.

If in addition to being mutually exclusive A and B exhaust the possibilities for what can happen (e.g. a coin flip can come up either A = heads or B = tails), we often say that A and B "partition", or [form a partition of,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set) the set of possibilities. But this is a strictly stronger condition than mutual exclusivity, and is not implied by mere mutual exclusivity.

Answer (score 1):

"Mutually exclusive" does not mean "A XOR B."  It means "NOT (A AND B)" or equivalently "(NOT A) OR (NOT B)."